# how to make databinding in CheckEd it with file WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I want to make binding betweeen CheckEdit and files txt

```
 string[] path1 = { "Fine.txt", "Debug.txt", "Info.txt" };
```

I give in data files and output them in a GridControl

I need to do so that you can select specific file

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCheckBockes}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="True"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Concludes Grid

```
   string[] path1 = { "Fine.txt", "Debug.txt", "Info.txt" };

    public List<DataText> list;

    public TextViewModel()
    {

        list = ReadTextFile.LoadDateListFromFile(path1);

   }

    public string[] MyCheckBockes
    {
        get { return path1; }
        set
        {
            path1 = value;
            OnPropertyChange("MyCheckBockes");
        }
    }
```

ReadTextFile.LoadDateListFromFile - parsing and out data in GridControl

Question!
how to make a binding that you can enable or disable certain data file

Comment: Are you sure you're not after a `RadioButton` instead of a `CheckBox`?

Comment: Yes, because I need to be seen one or two or all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bind to more than just strings. You will have to create some object to hold the enabled information as well. Perhaps something like:

```
public class MyCheckbox
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
```

Then your code would change to:

```
  MyCheckbox[] path1 = {
            new MyCheckbox() { FilePath = "Fine.txt", IsEnabled = false },
            new MyCheckbox() { FilePath = "Debug.txt", IsEnabled = true },
            new MyCheckbox() { FilePath = "Info.txt", IsEnabled = true } };

        public MyCheckbox[] MyCheckBockes
        {
            get { return path1; }
            set
            {
                path1 = value;
                OnPropertyChange("MyCheckBockes");
            }
        }
```

And your binding:

```
<dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding Path=FilePath}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
```